# FFT - Applying window on PCM data

Tags: c, signal-processing, fft, fmod, kissfft

I'm currently trying to reproduce the `getSpectrum` function of the FMOD audio library. This function read the PCM data of the currently playing buffer, apply a window on this data and apply a FFT to get the spectrum.

It returns an array of float where each float is between 0 and 1 dB (`10.0f * ( float)log10(val) * 2.0f` ).

I'm not sure of what I do is what I should do so I'll explain it :

First, I get the PCM data in a 4096 bytes buffer, according to the documentation, PCM data is composed of samples which are a left-right pair of data.

[image: data]

In my case I'm working with 16bit samples like in the image above. So, if I want to work only with the left channel, I save the left PCM data in a short array doing :

```
short *data = malloc(4096);
FMOD_Sound_ReadData(sound, (void *)data, 4096, &read);
```

So if a sample = 4 bytes, I have 1024 samples i.e 1024 shorts representing the left channel and 1024 shorts representing the right channel.

In order to perform the FFT, I need to have a float array and apply a window (Hanning) on my data:

```
float hanningWindow(short in, size_t i, size_t s)
{
    return in*0.5f*(1.0f-cos(2.0f*M_PI*(float)(i)/(float)(s-1.0f)));
}
```

whew `in` is the input, `i` is the position in the array and `s` the size of the array (1024).

To get only the left channel :

```
float *input = malloc(1024*sizeof(float));
for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    input[i] = hanningWindow(data[i*2], i, 1024);
```

Then I perform the FFT thanks to kiss_fft (from real to complex). I get a `kiss_fft_cpx *ouput` (array of complex) of size 1024/2+1 = 513.

I calculate the amplitude of each frequency with :

```
kiss_fft_cpx   c = output[i];
float          amp = sqrt(c.r*c.r + c.i*c.i);
```

calculate in dB :

```
amp = 10.0f * (float)log10(amp) * 2.0f;
```

`amp` is not between 0 and 1. I don't know where I have to normalize my data (on the PCM data or at the end). Also I'm not sure of the way I am applying my window on the PCM data.

Here is the result I get from a 0 to 20kHz song compared to the result of the getSpectrum function. (for a **rectangular window**)

[image: results]

```
             My Result                         getSpectrum Result
```

How can I achieve the same result?

Comment: On a speed note, you should really store the Hann window coefficients rather than computing them from trig each time.

Comment: no need to take the sqrt.  Note: 20*log10(sqrt(x)) == 10*log10(x)

Answer (score 2):

You're a little confused about log (dB) scales - you don't get a range of 0 - 1 dB, you get a range of typically 96 dB for 16 bit audio, where the upper and lower end are somewhat arbitrary, e.g. 0 to -96 dB, or 96 dB to 0 dB, or any other range you like, depending on various factors. You probably just need to shift and scale your spectrogram plotting by a suitable offset and factor to account for this.

(Note: the range of 96 dB comes from the formula `20 * log10(2^16)`, where 16 is the number of bits.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but oddly, when applying `20 * log10(amp)` I get values up to 120. It may be because of the (float) casting I do but not sure about that.

Comment: It's really only the *range* that matters - dB is a ratio relative to some notional 0 dB reference - you just need to look at the min/max values that you are getting and shift/scale accordingly to get a reasonable intensity range on your spectrogram.

Comment: The Hann window above multiplies by a average value of .5.  Also the max value of the signed 16 bit data is 2^15-1, not 2^16.  Backing off -6dB for each of these halving of scale sets the peak dB at 84dB